# how to use --no-data for few tables and full data for few tables in single command mysqldump?

Tags: mysql

I have scenarios like to back up the few tables structures and other few tables structure + contents.

I read about all the options of [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html)

It says that [--no-data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-data) will backup all the tables structures only like

```
mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p wp2 --no-data wp_options wp_users > mydatabase_backup.sql
```

but I want the same command to perform the both such as few tables only structures and few tables structure + contents.

Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to run two different commands

First one structure only tables **mysqldump** command

```
mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p wp2 --no-data structure_only_table > mydatabase_backup.sql
```

Then executed full table backups and `>>` helped to **merge both files**.

```
mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p wp2 full_tables >> mydatabase_backup.sql
```